# Is it possible to circumvent the limits of a 90 day Schengen visa by re-entering using a different passport? (I have more than 1)

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, passports, multiple-entry

I understand the limitations of the Schengen visitor's visa - I can stay no more than 90 days with the past 180. **My question is, can I leave the area and return on a different passport and begin a new 90 day visa?** The passports I have are US, Canadian and British. Like other's, I'm bummed that my British passport no longer affords me the right to visit the Schengen area for as long as I wish.

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: This question's definitely been asked before, but I can't find it right now. The short answer is no: the 90/180 day rules apply to **you** as a person, not to your passport(s).

Comment: Note that some Schengen countries like Poland and Denmark have different rules for US citizens due to pre-existing bilateral agreements. But as a general rule, no.

Comment: @jcaron good point.  I vaguely recall that some countries may have such agreements with Canada as well.  Again, such an agreement probably applies to the person rather than to the passport, but having both passports might increase the number of countries where this option is available.  It's even possible that some newer EU members might have an agreement with the UK predating the country's accession to the EU.